# Python How To Find Content in resp.text

Tags: python, request

I'm trying to find if this is found or not on a website.

My current code:

```
import requests

url = 'hidden'
resp = requests.get(url)

        if 'Simon \n <img class="Icon" alt="Member"' in resp.text:
            status = "found"
        else:
            status = "not found"

print(status)
```

(I have also tried without the \n). The issue is that they are not on the same line I'm guessing?

This is the output:

```
<img class="avatar" src='null' alt='Simon' />
Simon
<img class="Icon" alt="Member" title="Member" src="null">
```

The match has to be exact, as there are other users on the page as well!

Comment: `'Simon\n<img class="Icon" alt="Member"` there should not be a space before and after `\n`

Answer (score 0):

you could use a regex. That way if there any space or line breaks, you will still find the content on the website

```
pattern = re.compile('Simon[\s]*<img class="Icon" alt="Member"')

if pattern.findall(resp.text):
    status = "found"
else:
    status = "not found"
```

try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/3JDZo1/1)